# Angular: Custom Component in Custom Component

Tags: angular, components

After lots of searching: Is it possible to nest custom components in custom components?

I've created an empty angular cli - project and created `ComponentAComponent (selector: 'componentA')` and `ComponentBComponent (selector: 'componentB')`.

My app.component.html looks like:

```
<componentA>
  <componentB></componentB>
  <componentB></componentB>
</componentA>
<componentB></componentB>
```

What I would expect:

> Component A works!
>   Component B works!
>   Component B works!
>   Component B 
>   works!

But only

> Component A works!
>   Component B works!

gets rendered.
As I want to implement a custom list with custom list-items: What do I have to do to render custom components nested in custom components?

After a lot of google/ stackoverflow/ trial and error - grateful for any advice or link you can give me. Tried so much stuff with imports and declarations but nothing worked.

In case it helps I can provide a github repository with code.

Kind regards

**EDIT:** ABOS provided the correct answer. I added

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

to componentA.html and now all nested elements get rendered. So simple, but I did not find it. Thank you!

Comment: looks like you should use `<ng-content/>` in your componentA template.

Comment: Thank you *so much*! Now it works - finaly. If you post it as answer I will mark it as correct. I will also provide a working example. Where can I find this in the docs - I must have missed it. Again - thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add html/components dynamically, you can use `<ng-content>`. There are tons of tutorials on it, e.g. https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/